# What compression is used in txt file

Tags: compression, reverse-engineering, encode, text-compression

Hello what type of compression is used in this txt file

https://mega.nz/#!AEgwXZ7L!6pJEhKvOUKnWzqfmewNMtxb0uOn_qK_CTmW6TB6z3B0

want to convert it but don't know how is compressed this

Comment: This is not really a StackOverflow questions as it cannot help other people. This is similar to: Fix this code file. Also you have not provided us with any context.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you created your account here, it was suggested you take the [tour] and read the [help] pages in order to familiarize yourself with the site. If you had done so, you'd know this sort of question is not appropriate here. This site is for specific questions related to code or a programmers tool. Please do that reading before posting your next question here.

Answer (score 1):

It's not compressed. If it were, it would not be compressible by a factor of eight to ten with conventional compression software (e.g. gzip).